# Assert web element in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

How to assert web Element in pytest? I haven't used Pytest for UI testing before and can not figure out what library I should import. I am creating a new item and just want to verify if that item was created it should be equal to string.

```
item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(':nth-child(7) > ._3XkHf > ._3-t-g')

assert item.???? == '1000'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion you're trying to make hasn't much to do with PyTest itself, if you want to assert against the properties of the `WebElement` returned by `find_element_by_css_selector()`

I believe in your case `item.text` may be enough.

If you want to know what other properties are available in a `WebElement` you can check the docs [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html).